# Is Mila a nod to Jewel Staite's character on Firefly?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In episode S05E11 of "Stargate: Atlantis", Sheppard & Zelenka must hitch a ride on a Traveller ship. The captain takes them to the Engineering room, which is a horribly chaotic mess of hoses, tubes, & wires, She then introduces them to Mila, the 15-year-old mechanic who keeps the engine running, and ensures them that Mila can push the engines far past their specs. Mila herself seems to be a spunky young tom-boy who loves her ship, wears greasy coveralls, and braids her hair into two pigtail braids.

**Is the character of Mila a nod to Jewel Staite's identical character Kaylee on "Firefly"?**

Comment: It'd be double cool if Jewel Staite's character from _Stargate_ walked in there and showed those noobs how one should change a compression coil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until someone came from the production team and blatantly said that Mila is a nod to Kaylee this is pure conjecture, however, she does in terms of a character and her placement in the story have many parallels with Kaylee as you point out. I would like to think that as Firefly is such a cult series and the same being said for "Atlantis", that it was being headed by a few science-fiction enthusiasts who wanted to pay their respects to one of the greats.